# C2280: boost::container::map of uncopyable value type can't be std::move()'d?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, move, copy-constructor

I have an uncopyable class `Uncopyable` stored in `boost::container::map<K, Uncopyable>`. Another class, `Owner`, has an object of such map. The implementation of `Owner::Owner(Owner&&)` requires moving `map`. However, `this->map = std::move(other.map)` yields to C2280 in Boost's `pair.hpp`: "referencing a deleted function `Uncopyable::Uncopyable(Uncopyable const&)`".

Here's the minimal reproducible example. A few code aspects like the rule of five were omitted for brevity.

```
// Owner.h:
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>
class Key;
class Uncopyable;
class Owner {
private:
  boost::container::map<Key, Uncopyable> map = {};
public:
  Owner(Owner&&);
  Owner& operator=(Owner&&);
};
```

```
// Owner.cpp:
#include "Owner.h"
class Key {
};
class Uncopyable {
public:
  Uncopyable(Uncopyable&&) {
  }
  Uncopyable& operator=(Uncopyable&&) {
    return *this;
  }
  Uncopyable(Uncopyable const&)            = delete;
  Uncopyable& operator=(Uncopyable const&) = delete;
};
Owner::Owner(Owner&& other) {
  *this = std::move(other);
}
Owner& Owner::operator=(Owner&& other) {
  map = std::move(other.map);
  return *this;
}
```

**I forgot to mention `map` had a `Comparator` for the `Key` passed as the third template parameter. Maybe will fix the example later.**

What's the reason of the problem and how to get rid of it? Is it a bug in Boost? Is `pair`'s triviality somehow connected with this?

If it is important, I'm using C++17 with (probably) the latest stable version of Boost and MSVC. The `Uncopyable` class is actually `std::variant<Copyable, Uncopyable>`. The `map` is declared in .h with incomplete types which are complete in .cpp, where all the definitions are placed.

Comment: Have you defined move assignment for Owner? If not then `ownerA = std::move(ownerB)` will become a copy assignment.

Comment: @ALX23z interesting fact! Yes, all my classes have both move constructor and move assignment operator defined.

Comment: I don't immediately see the problem. Can you provide a [mre] to help us find out the source of the problem?

Comment: @L.F. OK, I've provided one, please check the updated version of the question.

Comment: Reproducible in GCC: https://wandbox.org/permlink/8HItTONq66LHOOgU Clang: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ewah4sZXLgnEJYvx shouldn't be a MSVC problem

Comment: @L.F. a bug in Boost? Or did I break their contract?

Comment: It looks like a bug in boost to me.

Comment: It’s not generally a good idea to define move construction in terms of move assignment—it involves several needless steps (like default construction).

Comment: @DavisHerring would you prefer implementing almost the same logic twice? Can the compiler do it for me?

Comment: @passing_through: The “copy and swap” idiom works for move-only types (and you probably want `swap` anyway).